Adding johnsonSU to arch_model python
I am writing a new class to be used with arch.univariate in Pyhton. It is meant to be the JohnsonSU distribution, that is already implemented in scipy as random variable (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.johnsonsu.html). The code is the following (sorry for the length but it is the MEW):
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import johnsonsu
from arch.univariate import Distribution
from numpy.random import RandomState, Generator
from arch.univariate import Distribution

class JohnsonSU(Distribution):
    """
    Custom Johnson SU distribution for use with arch_model.
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        random_state: RandomState | None = None,
        *,
        seed: None | int | RandomState | Generator = None
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(random_state=random_state, seed=seed)
        self._name = "Johnson SU"
        self.num_params = 2  # The number of parameters (a, b)
    
    def starting_values(self, resids):
        """
        Provide reasonable starting values for the optimizer.
        """
        return np.array([0, 0.01])  # Initial guesses for a and b

    def bounds(self, resids):
        """
        Provide bounds for the optimizer. For Johnson SU, a and b must 
        both be greater than 0 but not unreasonably large.
        """
        return [(-5, 5), (1e-2, 5)]  # Reasonable bounds for a and b

    def constraints(self):
        """
        Constraints for optimization: a, b > 0.
        """
        # Only enforce b > 0. No constraint on 'a'.
        return np.array([[0, 1]]), np.array([0])

    def parameter_names(self):
        """
        Return the names of the parameters.
        """
        return ['a', 'b']

    def loglikelihood(self, parameters, resids, sigma2, individual=False):
        """
        Log-likelihood function that accounts for conditional volatility sigma2.
        
        Parameters:
        - parameters: array of parameters (a, b) for the Johnson SU distribution
        - resids: residuals from the model
        - sigma2: conditional variances (sigma^2) from the GARCH model
        - individual: if True, return the log-likelihood of each observation
        """
        a, b = parameters
        var = johnsonsu.var(a, b).var()        

        z = resids.copy()
        
        # Compute log-likelihood using the normalized residuals
        log_pdf = johnsonsu.logpdf(z, a, b) #- 0.5*np.log(sigma2) 
        if individual:
            return log_pdf
        else:
            return np.sum(log_pdf)

    def simulate(self, parameters):
        """
        Simulate random data from the Johnson SU distribution using the given parameters.
        """
        parameters = ensure1d(parameters, "parameters", False)
        self._parameters = asarray(parameters, dtype=float)
        return self._simulator

    def _simulator(self, size):
        """
        Simulate random draws from the distribution for residual simulation.
        """
        a, b = self._parameters
        return johnsonsu.rvs(a, b, loc=0, scale=1, size=size, random_stat = self.random_state)

    def cdf(self, resids):
        """
        Compute the CDF of the residuals using the Johnson SU distribution.
        """
        a, b = self._parameters
        #return johnsonsu.cdf(resids, a, b) # equivalent to johnsonsu(a,b).cdf(resids)
        var = johnsonsu.var(a, b).var()
        return johnsonsu.cdf(resids, a, b, scale = 1/np.sqrt(var))

    def ppf(self, quantiles):
        """
        Compute the Percent-Point Function (inverse CDF) for simulation purposes.
        """
        a, b = self._parameters
        #return johnsonsu.ppf(quantiles, a, b)
        var = johnsonsu.var(a, b).var()
        return johnsonsu.ppf(quantiles, a, b, scale = 1/np.sqrt(var))

    def moment(self, n: int, parameters: None | Sequence[float] | np.ndarray = None) -> float:
        """
        Compute the nth moment of the Johnson SU distribution.
        
        Parameters:
        - n: The order of the moment (n=1 is the mean, n=2 is the variance, etc.)
        - parameters: The parameters (a, b) for the Johnson SU distribution.
        
        Returns:
        - The nth moment of the distribution.
        """
        if n < 0:
            return np.nan  # Negative moments are not defined
        
        # Ensure parameters are set and valid
        if parameters is None:
            assert self._parameters is not None, "Parameters must be set before computing moments."
            parameters = self._parameters
        
        a, b = parameters
        #return johnsonsu.moment(n, a, b)
        var = johnsonsu.var(a, b).var()
        return johnsonsu.moment(n, a, b, scale = 1/np.sqrt(var))

    def partial_moment(self, n: int, z: float = 0.0, parameters: None | Sequence[float] | np.ndarray = None) -> float:
        """
        Compute the nth partial moment of the Johnson SU distribution, up to a threshold `z`.
        
        Parameters:
        - n: The order of the moment (e.g., n=1 for mean, n=2 for variance, etc.)
        - z: The threshold up to which the partial moment is computed (e.g., left or right tail).
        - parameters: The parameters (a, b) for the Johnson SU distribution. If None, use fitted parameters.
        
        Returns:
        - The nth partial moment of the distribution up to the threshold `z`.
        """
        if n < 0:
            return np.nan
        
        if parameters is None:
            assert self._parameters is not None, "Parameters must be set before computing moments."
            parameters = self._parameters
        
        a, b = parameters
        var = johnsonsu.var(a, b).var()        

        # Separate the distribution at the threshold `z`
        # Partial moment for the left tail (values <= z)
        if z <= 0:
            left_tail_cdf = johnsonsu.cdf(z, a, b, scale = 1/np.sqrt(var))
            return johnsonsu.moment(n, a, b, scale = 1/np.sqrt(var)) * left_tail_cdf
        # Partial moment for the right tail (values > z)
        else:
            right_tail_cdf = 1- johnsonsu.cdf(z, a, b, scale = 1/np.sqrt(var))
            return johnsonsu.moment(n, a, b, scale = 1/np.sqrt(var)) * right_tail_cdf

This is supposed to be in line with the implementation for the other distributions inside the arch package. It needs to be added to the arch.univariate.distributions.py , and also the arch.univariate.mean must be updated to include its name.
The issue that I have is not about convergence, but rather with the Hessian matrix in the optimal point. If I run
mod = arch_model(np.random.normal(size=100), vol='Garch', p=1, q=1, dist='johnsonsu')
result = mod.fit(options = {'maxiter':10000}, tol=1e-10)
result.param_cov

I get that the Hessian matrix is singular. At specific inspection, I see that the current implementation is insensitive to the parameters alpha[1] and beta[1] that the arch_model.fit() gives, for example if I change scale of the data and so they always remain at the same level. This leads me to conclude that I might have found a (local?) minimum where the likelihood second derivatives wrt these two parameters are zero (flat surface). I tried varying tolernace, max_iter etc with no success. My take for now is that the loglikelihood of this class does not depend on the conditional variance sigma2 like for other arch_model distributions (e.g. https://arch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/univariate/generated/arch.univariate.SkewStudent.html#arch.univariate.SkewStudent), which in turn is function of alpha[1] and beta[1], but this is because the pdf of the johnsonsu does not depend on volatility. Any suggestion on how to solve this issue is appreciated
